# Protractor if ,else with (expect(condition))

Tags: if-statement, protractor, javascript-objects

in my script i need to include if and else statement,here is the code

```
if((element(by.model('trt_model')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(0).getText()).toEqual('Select Contract'))
{
    element(by.model('trt_model')).get(1).click();
}
else
{
    element(by.model('trt_model')).get(0).click();
}
```

if the expect condition fails , i want the script to execute the else part, but this is not working. 
when expect condition fails,the script is not executing the else part

kindly suggest how this can be resolved
Thank you

Comment: I don't know whether it's typo, You have missing parenthesis in `if`  condition also in all `element` selections.

Comment: ya its a typo. sorry for that.

Comment: Where is your `expect`? I don't see it in your if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have simplified your code and pasted below. You can try this one. Please let me know if you face any error with below code. Hope it will work.

```
element(by.model('trt_model')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(0).getText  
 ()).then(function(text){
        if(text==='Select Contract')
            element(by.model('trt_model')).get(1).click();
       else
           element(by.model('trt_model')).get(0).click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution Suresh, it is working perfectly fine:)

Comment: @HemaLatha. cool. Could you pease tick my solution as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long is your list, but it seems that you can simplify your code. How about use:

```
element(by.model('trt_model')).get(last).click();
```

instead of whole `if` statement?